# Azure VM Security

Tags: permissions, azure, azure-vm

With the move to Azure Cloud things are moving fast! I have a question based on Azure VM with a shared SQL Server containing multiple instances.

For example if a Azure VM has 5 instances on there each with different databases, and a vendor logs in to our Azure VM is there a way to lock down what they can access? I know you can assign DB_Roles for the vendor to only view the database they need, but how about for drives and the files within those drives?

Comment: I would highly recommend against giving a vendor RDP access to the VM at all. And if, for some reason, it is required - put their stuff on a dedicated VM. Too many possible issues where this goes horribly wrong for you.

Comment: Normally they would not need RDP access or personal access to any drives and files.  You can grant them appropriate access to a SQL instance, and grant that SQL Server instance (using the per-service SID) access to any local files and folders it needs.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you for your reply. Now for example say if we have one instance on that Azure VM with multiple databases connected to it, can I set the SQL Server Instance accordingly to the users login? E.G we have the D: drive where the data files are stored for lets say 10 databases attached to instance X, can I hide the rest of the 9 data files from the vendor who has logged in to view their own database?

Comment: @LowlyDBA Some of our SQL DB's require the vendors to log in and view stuff. Could you eloboarte further when you say put them on a dedicated VM? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better if you explained why they need to login to the VM? If they don't, then David's response is the direction you need to go.

Comment: @LowlyDBA We use off the shelf applications that vendors support and sometimes need to login to our VM's to carry out checks on the DB / SQL Server to identify the issues...

Comment: And why does that require access to the VM and not just a SQL server login?

Comment: @LowlyDBA Sorry I'm confused...So at the moment they RDP into the SQL server using the accounts they have setup in our AD and then login to use SSMS and sometimes move files around from one drive to another when there is a upgrade due etc...So the current setup was each instance had its own dedicated SQL server, but now going forwards with Azure some of these databases will be under one instance as a shared SQL server..